# very simple jquery selector doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

html code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>ajax</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p id="para">this is a sample paragraphe</p>

<script src="my.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my.js file code:

```
$('#para').click(function(){
    $('#para').hide();
    alert("para hidden ");
});
```

i start learning jquery but seems that my beginning is really bad , i would find an answer ..
please help

Comment: The first thing you need to understand is that jQuery can't work on DOM elements until they have been processed. Look at jQuery's ready function.

Answer (score 4):

Change the sequence of JS file. **Load jQuery first**

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="my.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In *my.js* file, Use [**document-ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#para').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        alert("para hidden ");
    });
});
```

Comment: :) small adjustment +1

Comment: @user3573297, As per your original sequence of file, js file starts executing as soon as loaded, thus when `my.js` was loading first you must be getting error in your browser console

Comment: Remember there's a shorthand for jQuery ready: `$(function() { //..your code.. });`

Comment: @Snorlax, I prefer to use `$(document).ready(function () { .. })` its more readable

Comment: But does the same... and it is shorter. It saves code.

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
<script src="my.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="my.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my.js call JQuery function, but the scrips of JQuery is not loaded yet